# Resulting list of ComponentMeasurements

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing

I detect a single bright object in an image with the following code;

[image]

```
binImage = Binarize[image, 35/255];
newImage = ImageMultiply[image, binImage];
result = ComponentMeasurements[
 DeleteSmallComponents[newImage, 2], "IntensityCentroid"]

{1 -> {71.0501, 56.9741}}
```

To get the coordinate I have to write:

```
result[[1]][[2]]

{71.0501, 56.9741}
```

Can the conversion to the coordinate be obtained different?

Comment: `1 /. result` will give the same answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to get individual measurements, apart from the obvious:

```
result[[1,2]]
```

As @bills commented:

```
1 /. result
```

You probably want to do something with the centroid, e.g. call some function - you can make that function accept data in `ComponentMeasurements` format:

```
foo[index_ -> {x_, y_}] := (* do something useful with x/y *)
```

and then apply that function to each element in `result`:

```
Map[foo, result]
```

Or, you can use replacement rules to turn `result` to any format you want, e.g.:

```
circles = result /. (index_ -> centroid_) :> Circle[centroid, 5];
HighlightImage[image, circles]
```

In recent versions of Mathematica, `ComponentMeasurements` can also return different output formats, e.g. `"PropertyAssociation"` returns an `Association` of property names to value lists:

```
resultAssociation = 
 ComponentMeasurements[
  newImage, {"Area", "IntensityCentroid"}, #1 >= 2 &, 
  "PropertyAssociation"]
```

> <|"Area" -> {45., 2.}, 
>    "IntensityCentroid" -> {{71.0501, 56.9741}, {67.0714, 54.5}}|>

(Note that I've replaced `DeleteSmallComponents` with a criteria function as 3rd parameter.)

```
resultAssociation["IntensityCentroid"][[1]]
```

> {71.0501, 56.9741}

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.